# Overriding parent theme file

Tags: child-theme

I have a search form on my site to find specific articles, the search functions are included in the theme folder

theme/widgets/search.php

the search.php file is included in two files where the actual form is.

For one particular users I need to make a change to a single line in the search.php file in a function, I have tried using a child theme and adding the amended file in the root, including it from the the child function file causes lots of 'function already declared' errors, presumably because the functions are declared in the parent search.php file and now being re-declared in the child search.php file.

How can I get this updated file or function to override the the file/function in the parent theme.

Comment: what theme are you using? what is the code to include the search template into those two files? what is the full code of the search.php?

Comment: How are you defining which user sees the changed form?

Comment: It depends on whether the parent theme has it defined as a pluggable function. This may help: https://www.mhthemes.com/support/overriding-parent-theme-functions-child-theme-tutorial/

Comment: @Michael The theme is a custom one, the search templates it referenced from the search form which is a widget that goes on any page. The full code of the search.php is too long for here.

Comment: @belinus I am forking the theme for this user.